# How to pass Visibility widget as a attribute?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to hide and unhide the item without wrapping the Visibility widget. (Passing like below).

```
TestItem(
        visible: false
        title: 'test',
        prefix: Image.asset(
          "images/test.png",
          height: 30,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          
        },
  ),
```

Common class that created for the items.

```
class TestItem {
  TestItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.prefix,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.visibility
  });

  final String title;
  final Widget prefix;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Visibility visibility;
}
```

Comment: it cannot pass like this

Comment: bool cannot assign to parameter type visibility

Comment: Why you don't use Visibility widget instead of TestItem ?

Comment: I want to pass visibility

Comment: it cannot wrap with visibility Widget according to my program @DanielRoldán

Comment: how are you using this class? It looks like it's not a widget itself though it seems like you want it to be. Or did you leave out some code?

Comment: this is inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong you are passing bool value which  cannot assign to parameter type Visibility.

make visibility type of bool like this-

```
 class TestItem {
      TestItem({
        required this.title,
        required this.prefix,
        required this.onTap,
        required this.visibility
      });
    
      final String title;
      final Widget prefix;
      final VoidCallback onTap;
      final bool visibility; // boolean type
    }
```

And the use-

```
TestItem(
       visibility: false //here pass bool value whatever you want
        title: 'test',
        prefix: Image.asset(
          "images/test.png",
          height: 30,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          
        },
  ),
```